# End of Input System.in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am having some trouble with sending my scala program the end of file command on my machine.  I am able to enter input, but when I want to signal the end of the input by entering Ctrl-D, sbt is not recognizing that signal.  I have also tried Ctrl-Z (I am on a mac), and Ctrl-C.  Ctrl-C works in ending sbt all together, but I have had no luck ending the input to allow my program to run.  Here is the code that I am running:

```
  val words = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(System.in).getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  val imp = new Imperative()
  val map = imp.countWords(words)
```

When I read from a file using the following code my program works no problem:

```
val words = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/path/to/file/input.txt").getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
```

I am on OS X 10.9, and using sbt version 0.12.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added OS, sbt version, and clarified reading from file.

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: As @JacekLaskowski said, please add some information to clarify, in particular the OS you are running this on, the version of sbt used and what you mean by "when I read my file"

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I run the code using "sbt run" in the project directory.

Comment: Hmmm, when I `sbt run` an app with the code I could `ENTER` to finish the words coming in (that surprisingly didn't let me enter more on separate lines). Could you show the entire application? I'm on Mac OS using SBT 0.13.1. Why don't you use `package` or sbt-native-packager?

Comment: I was able to just create a text file with my desired input and test the program by using 'sbt run < input.txt'.  Thank you for your help!